# Struct and Class error

Tags: c++, class, struct, structure

I have a struct

Inside myStructure.h

```
struct myStructure
{
    int myInteger;
    double myDoublesArray[4];
    char myCharArray[79];

};
```

Inside myClass.h

```
#include "myStructure.h"

class myClass
{
private:
    myStructure myStruct[4]

private:
    Prog1Class();
    ~Prog1Class();
    void setMyStructData();
};
```

Inside main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include "myClass.h"
#include "myStructure.h"

using namespace std;

void myClass::setMyStructData()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter an integer: " << endl;
        cin >> myStruct[i].myInteger;

        for(int j = 0; j< 5; j++)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a double: ";
            cin >> myStruct[i].myDoublesArray[j];
        }

        cout << endl << "Please enter a string: ";
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        cin.getline(myStruct[i].myCharArray, 79, '\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    setStructData();

    cin.get()
}
```

The errors i'm getting are " 'myStructure' : 'struct' type redefinition " , and " left of '.myInteger' must have class/struct/union "

I'm sure it's some simple mistake I've made with the structure, but I've looked around and everything seems to be correct to my noob eyes.  Thanks!

And this isn't homework.  I'm just trying to get back into programming, and understanding how some different things work, and I'm doing old assignments from other schools.  Thanks.

Comment: You may want to start off adding a semicolon after the definitions of your class and struct to avoid distractions from these missing.

Comment: What is `Prog1Struct.h`, should that be `myStructure.h`?

Comment: I added the semi-colons, thanks!  Already an answer posted for it, haha.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed the typo's, I didn't copy paste it in, I typed the whole thing, so there were bound to be a couple of small ones, but none of that fixed the problem.

Comment: @Slimmons: well, that's the obvious first error spotted. The actual error is slightly harder to see (missing include guards). ... and I'd _bet_ that adding include guards fixes the actual problem!

Comment: There are still more errors. Copy and paste the real code *before* you show it to us. Even better, post a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org). Better still, write your code gradually, from simple to complex, testing at every step; don't write a hundred lines of code and then expect it to run smoothly.

Comment: @Beta: That is something some professional developers should follow, too! When I my first project there were more than 40 people "programming" since about half a year with _ever_ compiling any of the stuff they had programmed. Once the infrastructure was set up to actually build something all this code went to the bin...

Comment: Good advice from all, thanks, The include guards fixed all problems but 1, that I posted below underneath the answer for include guards. Thanks for the tips.  Maybe i'll get less -1's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your key problem is that you don't have include guards: when including the same header multiple times the compiler sees the same definition multiple times and doesn't like that! You need to guard against that, typically using macros, e.g.:

```
// myStructure.h
#ifndef INCLUDED_MYSTRUCTURE
#define INCLUDED_MYSTRUCTURE

// struct definition goes here

#endif
```

(likewise for *all* other headers).

Comment: Hey, thanks, that fixed almost all of the errors.  I'm still getting 1 error though.  Inside of my main(), when I call the setStructData() function, it's saying setStructData identifier is not found.

Comment: @Slimmons: compilers are annoying and stubbornly read what you write not what you meant! Did you mean to write `setMyStructData`? Also, to use this member function it needs to be called on an object...

Comment: thanks, all problems solved now, I appreciate the help and information.

Comment: @clcto Just a note for anybody looking at this later, clcto shows examples of how to fix it.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting multiple definitions because you include the structure header in both the `myClass.h` and `main.cpp`. You want to use include guards: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard.

Also in your `main()` you are trying to access a private member function without having an instance of the class. There are a few issues here. First you need an instance. However you cannot create an instance in main because the constructor is private as well. Your `myClass.h` should look like this:

```
class myCLass
{
private:
    myStructure myStruct[4]

public:  // NOTE public here
    Prog1Class();
    ~Prog1Class();
    void setMyStructData();
};
```

Then in main you can create a `myClass`:

```
myClass c;
```

And then you can call the member function on `c` (because I changed it to public, otherwise you still would not be allowed to call it):

```
c.setMyStructureData();
```